# StackExchange inbox new notifications number does not match

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-exchange, global-inbox

Looks like minor bug, but still..

[image]

The number is 3 but I see only 2 new notifications.

Any idea? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probaly have multiple new comments in the same question.

Comment: I thought the number was only the new *items*.. well I'll have closer look and see. So you say if there are 10 new comments in single question with @Shadow in them, I'll see 10 in the red circle??

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - this is the case.  The # on the inbox is the number of new answers/comments/messages.  The collapsing (as you can see in the "8 comments" in your screenshot) is done at display time (as is highlighting), well after the # is served.  A few people may remember *waaaay* back when (for about a day or two) this was not the case, and the inbox was a lot more annoying to use.