# Snow Flake sitting alone in the dark, crying silently

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, winter-bash

See this?

> [image]

All parts of the new top bar has a tooltip, e.g.

> [image] [image] [image]

But the poor snow flake? Nothing. No tool, no tip.

Can a tooltip be added, to explain to the clueless user what this is all about? Something like "A list of hats you acquired across the network" sounds reasonable. :)

Edit: even in case of new hat(s) there's still no tooltip!

> [image]

User will just hover helplessly over the number, wondering what's going to happen when clicking it.

Comment: Wow poor thing. Wait till you realize that clicking on the help button won't close the Winterbash menu..

Comment: @ins wow good catch! It doesn't interfere so might not be a bug though. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's a really good free hand circle. You even kept it in the bar!

Comment: @SeanWM That's 3 years of practice right there... [It used to look like this...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71753/stackexchange-inbox-new-notifications-number-does-not-match)

Comment: Not only is the snowflake without tooltip but it doesn't behave as it siblings, opening the acheivement or inbox and moving the mouse over the other will open them... but not poor snowflake. Clicking the help menu close the inbox, so I think it should close the winterbash menu too.

Comment: @SeanWM what Mr. Insert said... and I have only Meta folks to thank for this awesome skill I acquired! ;)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau so true... it's like the black sheep of the family. It's there, it's alive, but it's so... different.

Comment: Also, it doesn't onhover like it's neighbours. But that's a really minor thing, just a little insult to the injury ;)

Comment: See below my answer - we have greater problem... our snowflake actually melted!

Comment: If this is still a problem in 6-8 weeks, the devs might be able to look into it then.

Comment: Meta.SO: [Add title attribute to the Winter Bash icon on the top bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312782/add-title-attribute-to-the-winter-bash-icon-on-the-top-bar)

Answer (score 8):

And this is nothing.... on SharePoint meta either somebody left the air conditioner turned on or the global warming is reaching us... but the the flake seem to have melted!

[image]

Are by any means our servers located nearer to the equator?

---

### Updated - Winter Bash 2015

Now the meta sites associated to a main site show the snow flake icon to. Still no tool tip though.

---

Comment: Per site metas do not have Winter Bash in them, by design (no hats too, as you can notice)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211712/152859

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Didn't know, I have only one account for Stack, Stack meta and SharePoint. Anyway, you ruined my fun. Bad, no unicorn dollar for you:P (just kidding, you should soon see a white owl with a invoice at your window)

Comment: Yup, got the bucks! :D

Answer (score 2):

A tooltip would be excellent for new Winter Bash users.

An example of a tooltip would be:

> Recent Winter Bash activity

or one that is related for towards hats:

> Recently earned Winter Bash hats

It goes great with the other tooltips, makes sense, short and straight-to-the-point, and starts with "Recently" like the other two tooltips. This is a great feature to avoid confusion and users dying from suspense.