# What is the new 'Snow-Flake' symbol?

Tags: support, design, top-bar, winter-bash, tooltips

Good day. Today I was just working when I saw that there was a snowflake in the top-bar-menu, and it had a purple notification number on it. I had never seen it before.

> Note: This has been solved now.

Is this a new StackExchange Meta feature? Or was it there already? What does it do? The tooltip for this literally says `Winter Bash`. What is `Winter Bash`?

Thank you.

> Note: This is not a duplicate of [Snow flake sitting alone in the dark, crying silently.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212617/snow-flake-sitting-alone-in-the-dark-crying-silently) That is simply a feature request asking for a (new) better tooltip for the snowflake icon.
>
> Note: This has been solved now.

Comment: The tag info for [winter-bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/winter-bash/info) is right there.

Comment: have you considered...clicking it? ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo I have but it says that I have earned `still fresh`. What does that mean?

Comment: @ArihanSharma So you didn't try clicking on the link to the whole page describing what it's about in detail?  The one right in the header?

Comment: @Servy I did but... what *is* the actual Winter Bash? Sorry, I know I am arguable.

Comment: @ArihanSharma After opening up the menu, did you click on the link in the menu to the page about the whole winter bash?  The one right at the top of the menu that you opened up?

Comment: @Servy Yes... thank you... it has been solved now.

Comment: Editing the question the way you are is considered vandalism. Please leave the question intact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to find out what the Winter Bash is will be to click the [Winter Bash 2018](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/12/winter-bash-2018-2) link that you can see on the right hand side of the picture below.

[image]